# Will I lose permission to comment if I start a bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, privileges

At the time I'm writing this, I have 77 reputation. I was thinking to add a 50 rep bounty for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974998/regarding-functions-from-r%C2%B2-to-r-continuity-and-differentiability), which has been unanswered for more than six months. If I do that, my reputation will go down to 27 reputation, right?

My question is, **will I lose permission to comment everywhere** (which is earned at 50 reputation)? I hope I won't, but if yes, should this behaviour be changed, or it is intended to be like this?

Comment: Sadly yes, but you will still be able to Comment on your own Questions and on Answers to those.

Comment: I'd like to point out the obvious consequence that by asking this question and getting lots of upvotes, this problem is neutralized.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: There is no reputation gained or lost from votes on meta posts.

Comment: Oh. Well nevermind then. I don't know what I'm talking about then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The privileges are tied to reputation, so if you offer a bounty and your reputation drops below a privilege threshold as a consequence, you lose the respective privilege until your reputation again rises above the threshold.

So if you offer a $50$-point bounty before you have at least $100$ reputation, you lose the "comment everywhere" privilege until your reputation again reaches $50$. You will of course still be able to comment on your own posts and answers to your questions.

This behaviour is by design, and very unlikely to be changed.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll wait until I reach 100 reputation first. Or maybe 150 so I can offer a higher bounty. By the way, if I offer a bounty and no one answers, will I regain the bounty reputation?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic: No.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic You "pay" the bounty for exposure. Just like advertising doesn't guarantee sales and one doesn't get a refund if the campaign fails, bounties aren't refunded when one gets no answer.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic By the way, this meta post gets your question a little exposure, maybe it will even get you an answer. It already got you a comment there.

Comment: "You will of course still be able to comment on your own posts and answers to your questions." What about the question he offered the bounty on? Could he comment on it after offering the bounty, if it wasn't his own question?

Comment: @bof No, unfortunately not. It would probably be too complicated to get such an exception into the code [too much work for too little benefit, it's rare that users offer bounties on other people's questions that take them below the comment privilege], although it would make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You will have 27 points, which is not enough to comment everywhere, or post other bounties.

You can regain the reputation by posting more questions and more answers.